# Mapping relationships where the JSON representation can hold either a nested object or an object ID (in RestKit)

Tags: restkit

Is it possible to get RestKit to properly map relationships where the property might contain either a nested object or an object ID?

The API I'm currently working with often returns deep cyclical object graphs where multiple occurrences of the same object are replaced with the object's ID.

A simple example:

Nested

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Post Title",
        category: {
            id: 1,
            name: "Category Title"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Post Title",
        category: 1
    }
]
```

Since the replacement can happen at any level manually fixing the JSON before mapping is not very practical.

Comment: I asked almost the same question